# Nginx and _GET PHP validation

Tags: php, nginx, get

I'm trying to do the following to be able to use my friendly URLs but I can't do it with NGINX, with APACHE if it works, what I want to do is this:

Use the following rule in nginx.conf:

```
rewrite ^ / ([- a-zA-Z0-9] +) $ /index.php?path=$1;
```

This so that when you want to access any page of my site only access by name once validated in PHP in this way:

```
if (isset($_GET["path"])) {
    if ($_GET["path"] == "start") {
        include "modules/start.php";
    }
}
```

But when I do this only 404 error appears ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use nginx, but the regex looks like it shouldn't have spaces.